# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError got this error while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, invalid-argument, mobilenet

While Training `ssd_mobilenet_v2` I got the following error:

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 7209, in raise_from_not_ok_status
> raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node _*wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_16_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input is empty.
> [[{{function_node case_cond_cond_jpeg_false_220}}{{node case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
> [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
> [[RemoteCall]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Tried training but got this instead, anyone can explain me what's wrong?

Comment: The error says "Input is empty", do you understand the error message and if not what did you search for what it meant? What don't you understand ?